# How to retrieve "Request Payload" from Chrome DevTools Network?

Tags: node.js, networking, google-chrome-devtools, webdriver-io, payload

I am using WebdriverIO v6.5 to test a web application.  I need to pull the JSON "Request Payload" of a certain object, shown here:

[image: Request Payload]

To accomplish this, I am using the `@wdio/devtools-service` (v6.4) service and have created the following method:

[image: Method]

However, the method does not print the JSON contents of "Request Payload".  It prints other information, but not the needed JSON.  Here are the results:

[image: Results]

What should I do so that I can properly pull the "Request Payload" JSON contents?  Am I in the right direction?  Is there an easier way to accomplish this?  I feel I am very close, but don't know how to proceed from here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/mock.html and get `postData` from the mock like this `yourMock.calls[0].postData`

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Check out also built in assertions for network requests https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio.html#network-matchers